# Help: TCL error in Iphone Application

Tags: iphone, tcl

I compile Tux Racer World Challenger application! But I got a problem with TCL. In some file of this application include:

```
#include TCL_HEADER
```

But when I compile I get error:

```
 fatal error: 'tcl.h' file not found
```

I have added libtcl8.5.dylib in to my project. I'm using Xcode 3.2.3
Please help me!

Answer (score 1):

You also need to make sure that the `tcl.h` file (and its supporting files `tclDecls.h` and `tclPlatDecls.h`) is somewhere on your project's include path. On my Xcode setup (which is admittedly old now) it's under *Project* **→** *Edit Project Settings* **→** *Build* **→** *Search Paths* **→** *Header Search Paths*.

I'm not sure where the Tcl public header files are located on your system; try using `locate '*tcl.h'` to find a copy (I believe there is one beneath the `/System​/Library​/Frameworks​/Tcl.framework​/Versions` if all else fails, but you should confirm this yourself). Note that you can use a Tcl 8.4 header file to build with a Tcl 8.5 library *provided* you are only using the API functions supported by 8.4; this means that it is not entirely critical that you match versions fully (still a good idea though). If you need 8.5 functionality (e.g., the dictionary API) then you must use 8.5 (or later) headers, obviously.